# awk join multiple lines

Tags: sed, awk

I want to join lines between opening tag and closing tag with class named "content_subhd",
For example:

```
<span class="content_subhd">1

2

3 </span>

<span class="xyz">1

2

3</span>
```

Output should be:

```
<span class="content_subhd">123</span>

<span class="xyz">1

2

3

</span>
```

How can this be achieve, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/<span class="content_subhd">/, /<\/span>/ {
  r = r ? r $0 : $0
  if (/<\/span>/) {
    print r; r = x
    }
  next
  }1' infile
```

If you want to replace the content of your existing file:

```
awk > _new_ '/<span class="content_subhd">/, /<\/span>/ {
  r = r ? r $0 : $0
  if (/<\/span>/) {
    print r; r = x
    }
  next
  }1' your_file && 
    mv -- _new_ your_file
```

Added solution for mass replacement (as per OP request):

```
find <your arguments here> | 
  while IFS= read -r; do
    awk > _new_ '/<span class="content_subhd">/, /<\/span>/ {
  r = r ? r $0 : $0
  if (/<\/span>/) {
    print r; r = x
    }
  next
  }1' "$REPLY" && 
    mv -- _new_ "$REPLY" 
  done
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
But how can i redirect the output back to the same file?
I try to add > to the end of line that print things but it seems not working.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help!
I'm a newbie to awk and not so fimiliar with it.
I am combining this script with find command to do mass replacement.
I think i need sometime to figure out the replacing of argument but already get great help from you. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: @felix, solution for mass replacement added.

Answer (score 1):

As sed is tagged in this question, here is a one liner:

```
 sed '/<span class="content_subhd">/,/<\/span>/{H;/<\/span>/{s/.*//;x;s/\n//g;p;};d}' source
```

All lines are passed through except in the special "span class" case. These lines are hived off to the hold space, newlines are removed and then what would have been a multi-line is printed instead.